# Git - Spontaneous "changes" in working dir upon checking out a commit

Tags: git

When I checkout a particular commit in my repo and immediately do a
`git status`, there is a file that shows up as changed. If I look at the
SHAs for my working copy and the copy in the index/repo, they are
indeed different. The working copy has carriage returns, and while I
*suspect* the copy in the index/repo does not have them, the output
from `git cat-file` on the repo SHA does have them. In fact, if I
redirect that output to a file and do a `git hash-object` of that file,
I get back the same SHA as the working copy.

Doing a `git checkout` on the file changes nothing, i.e. it is still
marked as changed in `git status`. Trying to checkout another commit
fails, as my "changes" to the file would be overwritten by the
checkout. Doing a `git diff` on the file returns nothing.

The repo has a `.gitattributes` file, which starts out with `* text=auto
!eol`. Every file in the repo is explicitly listed in `.gitattributes`
with `-text`, *except* the file that has the spontaneous "changes". On my machine, core.autocrlf is false.

This is running on Windows. Git version is 1.9.5.msysgit.1.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? It is almost as if git
is adding the CRs to the file at checkout, but not "realizing" that
when it comes to deciding if there are local changes.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I am pretty sure I have this figured out. Contrary to my belief, the file in the repo *did* have CRs in it, and was thus exactly equal to my working copy. However, since `* text = auto` was specified in `.gitattributes`, the "clean" version `git status` uses would have its CRs stripped, i.e. upon commit. So, git considers the files different.

An interesting thing to note is that while I was able to reproduce this with a test repository using `* text = auto` in `.gitattributes`, I could *not* reproduce it if I did not have that line, even while setting core.autocrlf to true. The documentation implies the behavior should be the same, but that is obviously not the case.